# Log all APDUs inside a Java Card applet

Tags: java, javacard, apdu

Is it possible to save all APDU commands sent to a Java Card applet inside that applet?

For instance: terminal sends `00 B2 01 0C 00`, I want to save it somewhere inside my applet in order to be able to analyse it later.

Comment: You mean to store inside the Java Card? Or in the runtime / terminal / IFD / etc. calling the Java Card?

Comment: I mean to store inside Java Card for later analysis

Answer (score 5):

Sure that's possible. It is required to generate a persistent buffer of some kind. There are various tricks to do this.

The easiest one is to generate a list, where each node holds an new array in which you copy the command. Simply determine the command size first, then copy everything in. Don't forget to copy in the Le bytes for type 2 and type 4 commands.

Probably the best method is to generate a huge array and copy each and every command to it. Persistent arrays are simply fields generated using `new byte[size]`. Note that the maximum size of the array is 32 Ki - 1You may want to store the size of the command before the command or in a separate persistent array.

As the amount of on card persistent storage is usually pretty minimal you may want to generate some kind of cyclic buffer, where you reuse or overwrite the oldest commands. Mind that there is often no garbage collection possible and if it exists it usually only runs during startup and it may take a long time.

You can immediately copy the header in the `process` method of the applet. You should only copy the rest of the command data once you receive the bytes, e.g. after using `setIncomingAndReceive` and finally `setOutgoing` / `setOutgoingAndSend` for the Le byte(s).

Finally you need some command to read out the log as well. Note that a command can be `4 + 1 + 255 + 1 = 262` bytes if you include the Le byte. A command response only holds 256 bytes + the status word. So you may need to read it out in multiple parts, e.g. using a counter to indicate the specific APDU and offset.

Extended length APDU's deserve a chapter all in themselves, so I'll leave them out for now.

---

I'll also leave the actual implementation as an exercise if you don't mind, you'd probably have an interface such as:

```
interface APDULogger {
    short logNewCommand(byte[] commandHeader, short commandHeaderOffset);
    void logNc(short nc);
    void logCommandData(byte[] commandData, short commandDataOffset, short commandDataSize);
    void logNe(short ne);
}
```

and

```
interface APDURetreiver {
    void retrieveCommand(short history, byte[] commandHeader, short commandHeaderOffset);
    short retrieveNc();
    short retrieveCommandData(byte[] commandData, short commandDataOffset, short maxCommandDataSize);
    short retrieveNe();
}
```

but mind you, this is just out of the top of my mind. You may want to keep some state too (calling the `logNe(short)` method signature twice is probably an error).

Comment: I didn't say it was easy per se.

Comment: +1 Cyclic buffer is a nice solution. However, be careful with its size - if the period is too short, you will damage your persistent memory very soon. Another thing is you should implement some kind of a switch for log enabling/disabling and you should enable it for debugging only - such a logging mechanism will slow down the whole applet significantly.

Comment: All true. Of course you have a choice: either use a lot of memory (which may not be there) *or* reuse memory. But you are right, usually after 10K writes or more the smartcard may call it a day. As for the slowing down: writes to persistent memory are usually very slow although it differs for each memory type.

Comment: I used your method about generation multiple persistent buffer. The problem is the card seem to die after some time, i killed few cards like that, not sure where the problem is. Here is my code: For log apdu: Data1 = new byte[25]; Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buffer, (short)0, Data1, (short) 0, (short)Data1.length); Here is code for read apdu: Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(Data1, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0, (short) Data1.length); apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) Data1.length);. Does javacard free memory on applet deletion ? Not sure why cards get killed. Thanks!